# boolean var does not stop function from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following image in my markup:

```
<img id="header_img" src="header_img.png">
```

pretty simple. Now I have two functions which do change the `src` of the image by hovering and one which changes the image source depending of the mouseposition in the window:

```
var trigger = true;
 if(trigger) {
    jQuery('body').mousemove(function(evt) {
    var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
        var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
          if (mouse_x <= window_width/3) {
            jQuery('#header_img').attr('src', 'left.png');
          }
          if (mouse_x >= window_width/3) {
            jQuery('#header_img').attr('src', 'right.png');
          }
   }); 
 }
```

and:

```
jQuery('#header_img').hover(function() { 
    trigger = false;
    jQuery(this).attr('src','rotate.gif')}, function() { 
    trigger = true;
    jQuery(this).attr('src','header_img.png')
});
```

so since I don't want to fire the `.mousemove()` function anymore if the image is hovered I avoid it by setting the boolean `trigger` to false. Unfortunenately it does not work. It even logs me `false` but the first function keeps firing. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `but the first function keeps firing. Why?` – because the mousemove event gets bound only once in the beginning, and then _stays_ bound. If you don’t need it anymore … then unbind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is already bound, so you need to either unbind it:

```
function bodyMouseMoveFunction(evt) {
    //your function here
}
jQuery('body').on('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveFunction);

jQuery('#header_img').hover(function() { 
  jQuery('body').off('mousemove');
  jQuery(this).attr('src','rotate.gif')}, function() { 
  jQuery('body').on('mousemove', bodyMouseMoveFunction);
  jQuery(this).attr('src','header_img.png')
});
```

Or move your trigger check:

```
jQuery('body').mousemove(function(evt) {
  if (trigger) {
    var window_width = jQuery(window).width();
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
    var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
      if (mouse_x <= window_width/3) {
        jQuery('#header_img').attr('src', 'left.png');
      }
      if (mouse_x >= window_width/3) {
        jQuery('#header_img').attr('src', 'right.png');
      }
   }
});
```